# Are these signs of bed bugs?

Tags: pest-control, bedroom, insect

I find these bugs crawling from under the bed :

[image]

I don't know what they are. I haven't seen them on top of the bed just on the floor. But I've been getting rashes all over my body even though I didn't see anything on me.

Comment: We've fought bedbugs before - I don't think that's a bedbug - bedbugs tend to be more round and flat.

Answer (score 1):

That does not look like a bedbug but more like a [Kissing Bug](http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/the-assassin-bug-facts-dangers-prevention-203253), or some other variant of Assassin Beetle. They bite (people) and sometimes spread disease.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what they are but I think I have fleas on the bed too which could explain the biting. There are like yellow translucent crumbs on mattress I wonder if that's their eggs? I had yellow plastic bags and found black spots on them.